# Can Blender unbridge (unloop) a mesh?

Tags: mesh, objects, add-on, vertices, edges

I am following a coffee cup tutorial where I have to bridge two extrusions. I did that but the edges are intersecting giving crappy results.

I saved AFTER the bridge - so if I have to recreate it I will - but was hoping to learn HOW to fix.

Attached are two images showing the problem. Thanks![image: Edge intersection]

[image: Picture 2 is another view showing edge issue]

Comment: The simplest way is just to delete the intermediary crossing faces and make new ones. This is a simple enough application that a more complex solution is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted the crossing faces and made new ones then re-bridged. Had the situation crop up a couple more times. Turned out my faces were not rotated towards one-another enough.

Answer (score 2):

The bridge edgeloops has an option that can help. The operator options are available by pressing <kbd>F6</kbd> and can also be found at the bottom of the tool panel on the left <kbd>T</kbd>.

[image]

The twist amount defines which top vertex bridges with which bottom vertex.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. add another loop cut in between
2. delete the new vertices

The bridge will be gone now